# State Machine into Flame from Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flame

just got a Question about the Flame Engine from Flutter.

Does someone know, how i can implement a Game State Machine into Flame? I tried something similar like you see in the code bellow, but when the GameState changes after a certain amount of time, the screen gets black.

Maybe someone of you had the same problem.

Greetz

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:fit_fighter/constants/globals.dart';

import 'package:fit_fighter/scene/dumbell_scene.dart';
import 'package:fit_fighter/scene/enemy_scene.dart';

import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';

import 'package:flame_audio/flame_audio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

enum GameState { dumbell, enemy }

class FitFighterGame extends FlameGame
    with HasDraggables, HasCollisionDetection {
  int score = 0;
  late Timer timer;
  int remainingTime = 5;
  late PositionComponent _gameInstance;
  late bool sceneLoaded = false;

  late GameState currentGameState;

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();

    FlameAudio.audioCache.loadAll([
      Globals.dumbbellSound,
      Globals.virusSound,
      Globals.vaccineSound,
      Globals.proteinSound,
    ]);

    currentGameState = GameState.dumbell;

    switch (currentGameState) {
      case GameState.dumbell:
        {
          _gameInstance = DumbbellScene();
          add(_gameInstance);
          break;
        }
      case GameState.enemy:
        {
          break;
        }
    }
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) async {
    super.update(dt);

    switch (currentGameState) {
      case GameState.dumbell:
        {
          (_gameInstance as DumbbellScene).myUpdate(dt);
          break;
        }
      case GameState.enemy:
        {
          if (!sceneLoaded) {
            _gameInstance.removeFromParent();
            _gameInstance = EnemyScene();
            add(_gameInstance);
            sceneLoaded = true;
            print("Scene Load");
          }
          break;
        }
    }
  }

  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO: implement render

    switch (currentGameState) {
      case GameState.dumbell:
        {
          break;
        }
      case GameState.enemy:
        {
          (_gameInstance as EnemyScene).myRender(canvas);
          break;
        }
    }
    super.render(canvas);
  }
}
```

Expected, that the change of the GameState would call a new Scene in Flame. For some reason the Screen beccomes black and doesn't show the new scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't manually call render or update methods like you're doing, override the `render` and `update` method in your components and put your logic and rendering code in there.

When you `add` a component that means that the game engine will call `update` and `render` automatically for that component.

Most of the time you never have to override `render` directly in your game class.

So when your state changes, just `remove` the old `_gameInstance` and `add` the new scene. You can also handle this with the `RouterComponent`.